# How to get the (n) index of character inside String?

Tags: java

suppose you have string like:

```
String longStr="someText1@someText2@someText3@someText@someText4@someText5@someText6@someText7@someText8@someText9@someText10@someText11@someText12@someText13@someText14";
```

how to get the index of the **10th** occurrence of the **@** character in the above String ?

i need the index to split from that index till the end.

Comment: Why do you need it? What are you trying to do afterwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) to Find the n-th index within a String

Answer (score 5):

`String s=longStr.split("@")[9];`

would give someText10

if you want the substring till the end

do

```
String sub=longStr.substring(indexOf(s));
```

or all in one:

```
String sub=longStr.substring(indexOf(longStr.split("@")[9]));
```

Comment: +1, OK, I am not going to write my lame answer which loops through indexOf 10 times

Comment: I don't see how your later edit would work... You'd substring from the index which is the length of the 10th interval between @s? Should that not be the sum of the lengths of the first 10 intervals?

Comment: The later edit, I assume would only work if the string content between `@` and `@` was unique, otherwise it may return the wrong index.  Your first answer was elegant.

Answer (score 5):

To get the index "manual" way (without StringUtils):

```
pos = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pos = longStr.indexOf('@', pos + 1);
}
```

To get the rest of the string without the index: use a regular expression. `"(?:[^@]*@){10}(.*)"` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String longStr="someText1@someText2@someText3@someText@someText4@someText5@someText6@someText7@someText8@someText9@someText10@someText11@someText12@someText13@someText14";
System.out.println(longStr.substring(longStr.indexOf(longStr.split("@")[10])));
```

Output:

```
someText10@someText11@someText12@someText13@someText14
```

Use following code if you want to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and you are not sure if string will contain 10 `@` in it.

```
longStr.substring(longStr.indexOf(longStr.split("@")[Math.min(10,Math.max(longStr.lastIndexOf("@"),0))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this method:

```
public static int indexOf(String haystack, String needle, int ordinal) {
    try {
        return haystack.length() - haystack.split(needle, ordinal + 1)[ordinal].length() - 1;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And calling like:

```
String longStr="someText1@someText2@someText3@someText@someText4@someText5@someText6@someText7@someText8@someText9@someText10@someText11@someText12@someText13@someText14";
int idx = indexOf(longStr, "@", 10);
System.out.println("Index of 10th occurrence: " + idx);
```

Will output `98`.

Answer (score 0):

testString.split("@", 11)[10]

This will return you required result.
Method split(String regex, int limit) - This method splits the string using regex for number of limit times and returns array.

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public class StringUtils {

public static int findIndexOfCharacter(String str, char ch, int num){
    if(str == null || str.equals("")){
        return -1;
    }

    if(num <= 0 || num >= str.length() ){
        return -1;
    }

    if(!str.contains(String.valueOf(ch))){
        return -1;
    }else{
        int[] indexOfCh = new int[str.length()];
        int index = 0;
        String[] strArray = str.split("");
        for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(strArray[i].charAt(0) == ch){
                indexOfCh[index] = i;
                index++;
            }
        }

        if(num > index){
            return -1;
        }
        return indexOfCh[num-1];
    }


}
```

}

JUnit Test:

```
@Test
public void testFindIndexOfCharacter(){
    longStr = "someText1@someText2@someText3@someText4@someText5@someText6@someText7@someText8@someText9@someText10@someText11@someText12@someText13@someText14@someText15";
    searchCh = '@';
    positionNum = 10;
    assertEquals(101, StringUtils.findIndexOfCharacter(longStr, searchCh, positionNum));
}
```